# Short Combinatorics problem.

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, combinations

A bank comes to campus and interviews each ics major  one at a time. After each interview they decide to hire that person or not. (a) There are n ics majors. How many decisions does the bank make? (b) How many ways are there t o choose students to get jobs at the bank? (c) Give two formulas for the number of ways to chose a subset of any size from a set of size n. Give a short combinatorial proof.

(a) Since there are 2 decisions and n ics majors then $2^n$ decisions because it's either a yes or no for each student.

(b) Not sure about this but I think its, either

$\binom{n}{k}$ or $\sum_{k=0}^{n}\binom{n}{k}$. Which is  the same as choosing a subset of the n students to get a job at the bank.

(c) $\sum_{k=0}^{n}\binom{n}{k}=2^n$. Not sure how to give a combinatorial proof. No induction or binomial just a short proof.

Comment: a) should be just n: they make n yes-or-no decisions.

Comment: @Bram28 Acutally yea since there are n students so n decisions. So would (b) be $2^n$?

Comment: For (a) why isn't it just $n$ decisions. They have two choices, but they are only making 1 decision per student. For (b) the second one is correct. The first formula would be correct only if we were told how many students the bank planned to hire.

Comment: @HiPolyEraser Correct! n yes-or-no decisions => $2^n$ possible outcomes

Comment: @BigAgnes yea so (a) n decisions since n student. For (b) i guess $2^n$. Actually the first formula was from the previous problem. Which I need to answer (c).

Answer (score 1):

For (c), I think Binomial Theorem is the way to go...

\begin{equation}
\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{n}{k} = \sum_{k=0}^n\binom{n}{k}\cdot 1^k\cdot 1^{n-k} = (1+1)^n = 2^n
\end{equation}

Comment: Yea I had this at first but  the prof. just wanted a more explanation type proof of why the two formulas are equal.

Answer (score 1):

$a)$ Since they are asking the number of decisions made by the bank, not the number of possible ways the bank can make decision, answer would be $n$.

$b)$ Now they asking number of ways bank can select students; it will be $2^n$.

$c)$ I am not clear whether you want this proof this way or not, but here it is :
Suppose you want to choose a subset. For each element, you have two choices: either you put it in your subset, or you don't, and these choices are all independent.So for each element you have two possibilities.Total number of ways to select a subset is $\underbrace{2 \times 2\times2 \dots\times 2}_{n ~~\text{times}} =2^n$

For the combinatorial proof of : $$\sum_{k=0}^{n}\binom{n}{k}=2^n$$

Think of counting subsets of a set in two ways.

$1)$ For selecting elements for a subset, you will either select none of them (null set) : $\binom{n}{0}$ ways, or you will select only one element : $\binom{n}{1}$ ways, or you will select two elements : $\binom{n}{2}$ ways $\dots$ or you will select all $(n)$ of them : $\binom{n}{n}$.Total number of ways will be - $$\sum_{k=0}^{n}\binom{n}{k}$$

$2)$ For each element, you have two choices: either you put it in your subset, or you don't, and these choices are all independent.So for each element you have two possibilities.Total number of ways to select a subset is $\underbrace{2 \times 2\times2 \dots\times 2}_{n ~~\text{times}} =2^n$.

Since both of the above methods should result the same ; $$\sum_{k=0}^{n}\binom{n}{k}=2^n$$

Comment: yea more of a explanation of the two formulas rather than a full proof.

Comment: @HiPolyEraser are you saying about $a$ and $b$?

Comment: For  $\sum_{k=0}^{n}\binom{n}{k}=2^n$

Comment: @HiPolyEraser Check my new edit, hope it answers you.

Comment: Yea that answers it. Thank you